# what are the core/basic functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

Does javascript have a set of core functionality. If so where can I find it?

Java for instance has all the java.lang packages which implement basic language functionality like String. Where is the equivalent of such functions (like window.alert()) implemented in javascript? Is there a set of core/basic functions that are shipped with every javascript implementation? What are these functions?

Thank you

Comment: Now now now now now. You can google this one.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_builtin_functions.htm

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: yes I looked at the above resources, but maybe I missed it there was no reference to window object there, neither in the ecma standards...so unless I missed it I have done my homework....and what are the functions associated with this object? like window.alert?

Comment: Here's the standard for the javascript language: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM is documented separately, like the [DOM window reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window). (This confused me too when I first started seriously working with JavaScript.)

Comment: thank you...it is confusing. I am glad you understood why I asked the question